# Spark MLlib: Including categorical features

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

What is the correct or best method for including categorical variables (both string and int) into a feature for an MLlib algorithm?

Is it correct to use `OneHotEncoder`s on the categorical variables and then include the output columns with other columns in a `VectorAssembler` like in the code below?

The reason is that I end up with a data frame with rows like this where it looks like `feature3` and `feature4` combined look like they are on the same 'level' of importance as the two categorical features singly.

```
+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
|prediction        |actualVal |features                                |
+------------------+-----------------------+---------------------------+
|355416.44924898935|990000.0  |(17,[0,1,2,3,4,5,10,15],[1.0,206.0])    |
|358917.32988024893|210000.0  |(17,[0,1,2,3,4,5,10,15,16],[1.0,172.0]) |
|291313.84175674635|4600000.0 |(17,[0,1,2,3,4,5,12,15,16],[1.0,239.0]) |
```

Here is my code:

```
val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("stringFeatureCode")
  .setOutputCol("stringFeatureCodeIndex")
  .fit(data)
val indexed = indexer.transform(data)

val encoder = new OneHotEncoder()
  .setInputCol("stringFeatureCodeIndex")
  .setOutputCol("stringFeatureCodeVec")

var encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)

encoded = encoded.withColumn("intFeatureCodeTmp", encoded.col("intFeatureCode")
  .cast(DoubleType))
  .drop("intFeatureCode")
  .withColumnRenamed("intFeatureCodeTmp", "intFeatureCode")

val intFeatureCodeEncoder = new OneHotEncoder()
  .setInputCol("intFeatureCode")
  .setOutputCol("intFeatureCodeVec")

encoded = intFeatureCodeEncoder.transform(encoded)

val assemblerDeparture =
  new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(
      Array("stringFeatureCodeVec", "intFeatureCodeVec", "feature3", "feature4"))
    .setOutputCol("features")
var data2 = assemblerDeparture.transform(encoded)

val Array(trainingData, testData) = data2.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

val rf = new RandomForestRegressor()
  .setLabelCol("actualVal")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setNumTrees(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In general this is a recommended method.
- When working tree models it unnecessary and should be avoided. You can use `StringIndexer` only.

Comment: What does this mean? StringIndexer only? How can you feed an index column to a decision tree? They take one column of feature vectors...